# How to wait for JavaScript function to complete in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, async-await

I am trying to fetch data from an endpoint in react but don't know exactly how can I wait for the called function to return and then pass the cursor to next line.

FetchData.js

```
// ...
componentDidMount () {
        const url = 'http...';
        const options = {
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            method: 'GET'
        }
        const data = fetchDataFromUrl(url, options);

        this.setState({ item: data },
            () => this.updateItem())
}
console.log(this.state.item)
// ...
```

fetchData.js

```
export const fetchDataFromUrl = (url, options) => {
    const repsonse = fetch(url, options)
    .then(res  => res.json())
    .then(data => { 
        return data 
    })
}
```

This does return the `data` but in console.log() I get undefined, after sometime (ie in some other function) I am able to see the `data` contents. How can I wait for the `fetchDataFromUrl` function to fetch the data before the state gets updated. I used
`const data = async() => fetchDataFromUrl(url, options);` but it does not help.

Comment: [Fetch is asynchronous.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)  Have you tried await `await fetch(...)`?

Comment: `fetchDataFromUrl` **has no return statement**

Comment: I think I have done it more pythonic way @Quentin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use, async and await for your requirement

```
componentDidMount () {
      this.getData()
}

getData= async()=>{
const url = 'http...';
        const options = {
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            method: 'GET'
        }
        const data = await fetchDataFromUrl(url, options);

        this.setState({ item: data },
            () => this.updateItem())
}
```

user fetch function should also be async function.

```
export const fetchDataFromUrl = async(url, options) => {
    const repsonse = await fetch(url, options);
      return repsonse; //Modify you response
}
```